# how to pass the value of a global javascript variable in one xsl page to another xsl page?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

some code ....
<xsl:template match="/OUTPUT">
    some code

var outPut= "";

function createOutPut(){
    some code
}
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to pass a value of outPut to another xsl page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
<xsl:param name="chkNode_val"/>


<CANALE><xsl:value-of select="//PARM[@name='channel_val']"/></CANALE>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if my outPut != "" then i need to change the value of CHANNEL.

i have never worked with xsl

any advice ?

I haven't tried anything yet because I'm thinking about it

Comment: We need more info on your set-up. (webserver?)
Normally you would post the value of your javascript to a server that uses that value in a second xslt-transformation...